# Space between text and its following figure

Tags: spacing, floats

How can I make some space between the text and its following figure? (Only once and not for the whole document).

Comment: A phantom space between a phantom text and a virtual figure? ;o)

Comment: This doesn't make sense. The figure doesn't follow the text. It may end up after the text, but it is just as likely (maybe more likely) to end up before the text or on another page altogether.

Comment: As with your earlier question, so again. We need a minimal working example. Please ensure that the code you post is complete - can be compiled as is.

Comment: @cfr Obviously it's not adjacent to the text. I need to make some space between a figure and its preceding text; A customized space between text and its following figure for one specific figure.

Comment: I did not suggest it would be adjacent to the text. That is more-or-less impossible, at least in one column format. I said that it makes no sense to speak of 'the figure which follows the text' because it might very well *not* follow the text since it is, after all, a figure and figures are, after all, essentially things whose locations are up for grabs. Figures *float*. It might float before the text, after later text, to another page, to the end of the document or .... Rarely will it follow the text just before it in the source. It's *possible* it might happen coincidentally, but unlikely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Text
\begin{figure}\centering%
\vspace{1ex}%
\includegraphics{image.jpg}%
\end{figure}
```

As of now, that's the best I can think of.

If you include a minimal working example above, we could potentially try to be a tiny bit more precise.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Note that if this figure floats, e.g. to the top of the page, then the space will still be included.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant LaTeX parameters are:

- `\intextsep`: the space between text and floats in the running text
- `\textfloatsep`: the space between a float at the top of the page and the text, also the space below text and a float at the bottom of the page
- `\floatsep`: the space between to consecutive floats

Thus you should be adjusting the first two of these parameters.  Here is a silly example where the `\intextsep` is increased and the `\textfloatsep` is set to zero, you will want to use other values:

In text example:

[image: In text float]

Top of page example:

[image: Float at top of page]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\intextsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0cm}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[htp]\centering
\rule{1cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-5]

\begin{figure}\centering
\rule{1cm}{3cm}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-7]

\end{document}
```